# XP installation on second drive

Tags: windows-xp

I have Windows XP SP2 installed. I want to install the same exact thing on a 2nd hard drive, make it bootable, installed in the same machine as a backup.

The install routine for XP starts just fine, and I got it to the point where it was asking for the key, but before I continue I want to know this: Can I tell it to install on drive `D:` and not drive `C:` the drive I am running it from? And will it leave my current running version of Windows XP on drive `C:` untouched? Just install itself clean on the new drive `D:`?

Comment: Yes;  You can indeed do this.  Be sure you make appropriate backups.  You should also consider NOT using SP2 since its extremely insecure.

Answer (score 0):

If you get to the point, where you are prompted for the Windows key, you've already gone too far. - Selecting which drive to install to, is done during the "DOS boot" at the beginning of the Windows installation. Aprox. 2 min. after booting from the installation disc. - When you are asked to format the drive, you should be able to select drive_0 (C:) or drive_1 (D:).

Btw. XP SP2 is missing a lot of updates. - To get them coming automatically, you need to install SP3, which can be optained from MicroSoft as an offline-package. You also need this to install Internet Explorer 8.